# How does kafka know whether to "roll forward or roll back" a transaction?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

From [the exactly-once KIP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging), concerning producer idempotency upon application restart with `InitPidRequest`:

> 2.1 When an TransactionalId is specified If the transactional.id configuration is set, this TransactionalId passed along with the
>   InitPidRequest, and the mapping to the corresponding PID is logged in
>   the transaction log in step 2a. This enables us to return the same PID
>   for the TransactionalId to future instances of the producer, and hence
>   enables recovering or aborting previously incomplete transactions.
>
> In addition to returning the PID, the InitPidRequest performs the
>   following tasks:
>
> 1. Bumps up the epoch of the PID, so that the any previous zombie
>      instance of the producer is fenced off and cannot move forward with
>      its transaction.
> 2. Recovers (rolls forward or rolls back) any
>      transaction left incomplete by the previous instance of the producer.
>      The handling of the InitPidRequest is synchronous. Once it returns,
>      the producer can send data and start new transactions.

When the producer fails and is started again and `InitPidRequest` is executed, what situations are the last transaction 'rolled forward' (I guess this means committed) or 'rolled back'?  How is this controlled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key component that enables Kafka to achieve this is the *Transaction Coordinator*. This was introduced as a part of the KIP that you've mentioned. The transaction coordinator is constructed by the broker as a part of the initialisation process and maintains the following information in memory:

1. A map from `TransactionalId` to assigned `PID`, current epoch number (Unix timestamp) and the transaction timeout value
2. A map from `PID` to the current ongoing transaction status of the producer indicated by the `PID`, the participant topic-partitions and the last time when this status was updated

**Now, to answer your question on rolling forward or back a transaction**:

When a producer fails and is restarted, it sends a new `InitPidRequest` to the Transaction Coordinator if the producer comes with a non-empty `TransactionalId` (supplied as a configuration parameter by the producer application).

The Transaction Coordinator on receiving this request then checks if there is already an entry with the supplied `TransactionalId` within the in-memory mapping (Point 1 above). If there exists a mapping, it will look for the `PID` in the second in-memory map (Point 2 above) to check if there is any ongoing transaction against that `PID`:

- If there is an on-going transaction that is in started status i.e. `BEGIN`, then the transaction will be aborted 
  (***Note***: *This is the **rolled-back** version*)
- If there is an on-going transaction that has started and is in either `PREPARE_ABORT` or `PREPARE_COMMIT`, then the Transaction Coordinator will wait for the transaction to go through to either `COMPLETE_ABORT` (***rolled-back*** version) or `COMPLETE_COMMIT` (***rolled-forward*** version).

After this, the Transaction Coordinator responds with the latest `PID` and the epoch timestamp for the `TransactionalId` and the producer can then start sending new transactions.

I've tried to keep the explanation to the minimum but if you're interested in more details then here's the [detailed design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11Jqy_GjUGtdXJK94XGsEIK7CP1SnQGdp2eF0wSw9ra8/edit#heading=h.xq0ee1vnpz4o) for your reference.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That was a fantastic answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @b15 - Thanks! I'm glad you found it useful. :)